# Image based collision detection taking transparency into account

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Basically this is my code to check if two `UIImageView`s collide:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(self.fishImage.frame, self.minebomb.frame))
{
    // some code
}
```

The code above only detects when the two frames collide. How do I detect when non-transparent pixels collide?

Comment: Is the real question: How do I detect if two overlapping images have common non-transparent pixels?

Comment: Yea, probably. Do you have the answer?